# Check constraint only one column can hold a value

Tags: sql, t-sql

So i have a table in which i have two [column]id and i want to add a constraint that say that only one of them can hold a value. (one must be null and the other not).

no matter what i try i get this

The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CheckOnlyOneColumnIsNotNull". The conflict occurred in database "", table "dbo.table".

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [c1] [bigint] NULL,
    [c1] [bigint] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([c1])
REFERENCES [dbo].[c1table] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([c2])
REFERENCES [dbo].[c2table] ([Id])
GO



ALTER TABLE table
ADD CONSTRAINT CheckOnlyOneColumnIsNotNull
CHECK 
(
    (C1 is not null and c2 is null) or (c2 is not null and c1 is null)
)
GO
```

Comment: Note able to reproduce this issue: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c91252d8c10a3999da601b041cdd162d. In which version of SQL Server (or in which TSQL database) are you running this?

Comment: I *assume* that in **your** environment the table, `[dbo].[table]`, already has data in it, and that at least one row has either both `NULL` or both non-`NULL` values for `c1` and `c2`.

Comment: Also, side note, that `CREATE` will fail as you have 2 columns called `c1`. I assume the second should be `c2`.

Comment: The code you've posted is valid (after fixing the minor typos) and will not cause this problem as is. In fact, I'm not even sure how an alter table can conflict with a check constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I have two options to solve this:

**Option # 1:**

```
CONSTRAINT at_least_one_not_null CHECK (
        (c1 IS NOT NULL AND c2 IS NULL) OR
        (c1 IS NULL OR c2 IS NOT NULL)
    ),
```

**Option # 2:**

```
CONSTRAINT at_least_one_not_null CHECK (
            COALESCE((c1)::BOOLEAN::INTEGER, 0) +
            COALESCE((c2)::BOOLEAN::INTEGER, 0) = 1
    )
```

**Note:**

Besides that, on your example:

```
ALTER TABLE table
ADD CONSTRAINT CheckOnlyOneColumnIsNotNull
CHECK 
(
    (C1 is not null and c2 is null) or (c2 is not null and c1 is null)
)
```

...you are using C1, and the real name of the column is c1 (in lowercase). Maybe that's why it's not working.